# Using angular2-meteor and useraccounts

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts, angular2-meteor, meteor-useraccounts

I was wondering how one could go about using the useraccounts package with angular2-meteor to create a custom UI for logging in.

I was following the tutorial for angular2-meteor  (http://www.angular-meteor.com/tutorials/socially/angular2/user-accounts-authentication-and-permissions)

but I cant see what would need to be done to use useraccounts instead of accounts-ui.

Best,
D

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this module as Blaze as dependecies, i don't think it's compatible with Angular 2